# Yichud with Jewish man that is "married"/together with a non-Jewish woman?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty

Is it mutar to be in the same house with a "mixed" couple [i.e. a Jewish man that is "married"/in a monogamous relationship of some sort with a gentile woman (since marriage between a Jew and a heathen is not valid anyway)], or is this a violation of yichud? As far as I know it is mutar for a  Jewish man to be in yichud with a non-jewish couple, since she is afraid of her husband, but it is not allowed for a Jewish woman in the same situation, since the wife is not makpid on her husband.

Comment: Can you [edit] to indicate a source or reasoning for the last sentence?

Comment: Can you also explain a bit more who you are referring to? Is this a Jewish woman in the house with a mixed couple? A Jewish man? Are you asking if the 3rd person violates Yichud? Is the 'married' Jew violating Yichud (granted, being married to a non-Jew is a more pressing issue, but you might be asking if there is an additional issue of Yichud too)? While it might sound like I'm being picky, I think each one of those cases are discussed separately in Halachah.

Comment: @warz3, your [suggested edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/18922) has been rejected; I don't think that what you wrote is necessarily the intent of that last sentence -- I think Hugh was trying to say that there is no yichud with gentiles *in general*, and not just in this situation (that the husband is around).

Comment: From what I have learned around this site, it seems clear to me that the mixed couple is not considered "married" in any halachic sense -- however that would bear upon the situation.